# Tensorflow prediction binary strings

Tags: tensorflow, binary, conv-neural-network

i'm trying to create a convolutional neural network, which predicts whether or not to sell for a hydropower dam, the issue i am having is the output. I input two inputs, price(a normalized float) and waterinflow (either 1 or 0 at this point).

My issue is that running this and trying to get the answer as a set of actions 0/1, gives me floats which do not make any sense other than if the output is set as the corresponding number instead of the set of actions. This is fine when the amount of actions are small, but will be horrible later on when the number of actions are extended.

Does anyone know how i can make it so that it outputs the actions as either 0 or 1, instead of the floats which seem to be certainty of the prediction.

Meaning if there are 4 actions, and the correct answer is 0, 1, 0, 1, then the predictions should be in the same form(4 actions either 0 or 1)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi @H0len, this can certainly be done.  I'll write up a solution but in summary what you will add is a rounding layer after your softmax but not used by your backprop function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Binary output from Normalized Probability

What you are looking for is a method of converting your normalized probability output to a binary one.

This is very straight forward in Tensorflow and involves added a **tf.round** function.  The trick is to make sure you do not use the output **tf.round** in training.  This is best demonstrated using a working code example.

## Working code example

This code calculates the XOR function using a neural net.  The outputs are y_out *(the probability output)* and y_binary *(the casting of the probability output to binary)*

```
### imports
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

### constant data
x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[1.,0.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[0.,1.]]

### induction
# 1x2 input -> 2x3 hidden sigmoid -> 3x1 sigmoid output

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 , shape=[None,2] )
y0 = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 , shape=[None,2] )

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2,3] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 )

# Layer 2 = the 3x2 softmax output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3,2] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_logit = tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2
y_out = tf.nn.softmax( y_logit )
y_binary = tf.round( y_out )

### loss

# loss : a loss function that uses y_logit or y_out , but NOT y_binary
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )

# training step
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)


### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )

  print "\nloss"
  for step in range(500) :
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x0:x,y0:y_})
    if (step + 1) % 100 == 0 :
      print sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x0:x,y0:y_})

  y_out_value , y_binary_value = sess.run([y_out,y_binary], feed_dict={x0:x,y0:y_})
  print "\nThe expected output is :"
  print np.array(y_)
  print "\nThe softmax output is :"
  print np.array(y_out_value)
  print "\nThe binary output is :"
  print np.array(y_binary_value)

print ""
```

## Output

```
The expected output is :
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]

The softmax output is :
[[ 0.96538627  0.03461381]
 [ 0.81609273  0.18390732]
 [ 0.11534476  0.88465524]
 [ 0.0978259   0.90217412]]

The binary output is :
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
```

As you can see, you can retrieve the probability outputs OR the probabilities cast as binary and still have all the benefits of classic logits.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is important to note that the output of neural nets are actually posterior probability computed on each element of the classes present---for a typical classification problem.
The figures returned tells you how likely is the ouput to be of class A, B, C given the input x. So that you can not expect to get 0 or 1 always.

```
#An example would be if I get 
Output = [0.5,0.2,0.3] given input x. 
#I predict the class should be A because it has posterior of 0.5
(the    highest value of the 3 values returned).
Class = A (0.5)
# Or I might as well round it up. Tensor flow can do this for you
```

So I guess  you should get the output and apply probabilistic assumptions thats fit your model like say the highest value in the returned predictions gives the class it belongs.
It might not be easy to wait for absolute one or zero prediction.

Be careful of this fact I wrote above. Its a common mistake. And please do read the paper below. Once you have posteriors, you can add and build models on them. There is no limitation to what you can achieve!

For example you can apply Gaussian Mixture models/ Markov models/Build decision Tress/Combine expert systems on the output, those are the elegant and scientific approach.

Read this paper for more info.
http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/NeuralNetworksPosteriors_Lippmann1991.pdf

Hope it helps!